# How to change textarea size on html?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to set my textarea size to 64%, but I can't. Can you help me to do this. Thanks for your help :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
div.c18 {position: absolute;width:64%;left:18%}
div.c7 {position:relative;overflow:hidden;left:18%;}
</style>


<div class="c7">OTHER</div>
<div class="c18">
<input type="textarea">
</div>
</br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are using wrong input type. try this: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_textarea.asp

Comment: thanks for your help it's working but is it possible to set size with % ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width of the child `<input>` or `<textarea>` to 100% so it fills the parent that is 64%

```
<input type="text" style="width:100%">
```

This can obviously be changed to a stylesheet  rule

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mzzwxm7j/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

First of all the textarea shall be used by textarea html tag
And to give height and width to textarea "rows" and "cols" property will be used. Please refer below code.

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
```

Comment: hard to make it responsive using `cols`

Comment: You can give id or class in the textarea and based on it give CSS on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add how many rows and columns you want.

You can do like this:

```html
<textarea rows="10" cols="80">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam non augue nec risus lobortis pulvinar. Mauris imperdiet orci vitae commodo condimentum. Nam molestie risus iaculis enim dictum egestas. Vivamus commodo mauris consectetur diam fringilla, ut tempor nulla volutpat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla feugiat fringilla turpis in feugiat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean laoreet orci et varius fermentum.
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving width to the container, give a specific width to the `textarea`. Like:

> CSS

```
#area { width: 50%; }
```

> HTML

```
<textarea id="area">
</textarea>
```